# How to open app from email URL in iOS 9?

Tags: ios, swift, swift2, ios9

I've tried something like:

In the AppDelegate:

```
func application(application: UIApplication, handleOpenURL url: NSURL) -> Bool {
    var returnValue = false
    let urlString = url.absoluteString
    print(urlString)
    if(urlString.hasPrefix("")){
        returnValue = true
    }
    return returnValue
}
```

In the info.plist

```
<key>CFBundleURLTypes</key>
<array>
    <dict>
        <key>CFBundleURLName</key>
        <string>co.example.ExampleApp</string>
        <key>CFBundleURLSchemes</key>
        <array>
            <string>example</string>
        </array>
    </dict>
</array>
```

But doesn't work. I want the app opens from a link that I send via email, anyone has an idea to make it work?

Comment: Did you follow [this example](http://stackoverflow.com/documentation/ios/5173/deep-linking-in-ios/19598/adding-a-url-scheme-to-your-own-app#t=201609071346266107572) from documentation?

Comment: What link do you send via email? It should look like `example://some_path/`

Comment: yes @iSashok, but still doesn't work.

Comment: `handleOpenURL `method deprecated from ios9. Try to use this `optional func application(_ app: UIApplication, 
                     open url: URL, 
                  options: [UIApplicationOpenURLOptionsKey : Any] = [:]) -> Bool`

Comment: Thanks @iSashok was that :D

Comment: I am working an app that providing browsing. I tried to add this to the plist. but it doesn't work. I am using Xcode 9, swift4 and iOS11.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

For future users, as @iSashok mentioned in the comments, the handleOpenURL function [is deprecated as of iOS 9](https://developer.apple.com/reference/uikit/uiapplicationdelegate/1622964-application).

For newer versions of iOS you need to use the following function ([Apple Docs](https://developer.apple.com/reference/uikit/uiapplicationdelegate/1623112-application)):

```
optional func application(_ app: UIApplication, 
                 open url: URL, 
              options: [UIApplicationOpenURLOptionsKey : Any] = [:]) -> Bool
```

You'll be able to keep the body of the function the same as before, and now it will work.